# Finding Acceleration of Two Masses in an Ideal Pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration, friction

I am stuck on this problem:

**Two masses are connected by a string which goes over an ideal pulley. Block A has a mass of 5kg and can slide along a rough plane inclined 30 degrees to the horizontal. The coefficient of kinetic friction between block A and the plane is 0.200. Block B has a mass of 4kg. What is the acceleration of the blocks?**

I know that in order to get the acceleration $F=ma$ must be used. I know $F_n$ is $(9kg)(9.8 m/s^2)= 88.2 N$. But how do I solve for F in order to get the acceleration? Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Draw a diagram and label all the forces you think are relevant. Where is block B? Is it hanging free? Is it also on the rough plane? It makes a big difference... See if you can figure out the net force due to gravity on the two blocks.

Comment: And remember that the tension in the string will be the same throughout its entire length.

Answer (score 1):

You analize the two objects separately and write the equation for the forces on each. The link between the equations is that the tension $T$ and the acceleration $a$ is the same for both bodies, using that you can solve your equations for the unknown forces

Comment: Good hint. I think that a diagram is really needed...